# JS condition not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

Basal metabolic rate should have different values for different genders. My calculator shows the result for male whether male or female radio button is selected.

BMR calculation for men BMR = 66.5 + ( 13.75 × weight in kg ) + ( 5.003 × height in cm ) – ( 6.755 × age in years )
BMR calculation for women BMR = 655.1 + ( 9.563 × weight in kg ) + ( 1.850 × height in cm ) – ( 4.676 × age in years )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script>

var bmr;
function funcCalc() {
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
var weigth = document.getElementById("weigth").value;

if (gender == "masc") {
bmr = 66.5 + ( 13.75 * weigth ) + ( 5.003 * height ) - ( 6.755 * age )
}  else {
bmr = 655.1 + ( 9.563 * weigth ) + ( 1.850 * height ) - ( 4.676 * age )
}
document.getElementById("lblResult").innerHTML = bmr;
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="#">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="masc" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="fem"> Female<br>
  Age:<br>
  <input type="number" id="age" value="20"><br>
  Height:<br>
  <input type="number" id="height" value="180"><br>
  Weight:<br>
  <input type="number" id="weigth" value="80"><br>
</form>

<button type="button"
onclick="funcCalc()">
Result</button>

<p id="lblResult">BMR</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have two elements with the `gender` ID. There should only be one ID on a page. You're always going to get the first.

Comment: Since there's only two, you could read its `.checked` property instead of its value. Then if `true`, you know it's `masc`, otherwise `fem`.

Comment: Otherwise, use `.querySelector` to get the checked one. `var gender = document.querySelector("input[name=gender]:checked").value`

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `id` attribute must be unique on every document. So your HTML is invalid. Instead, you could use [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) to get the elements and check for the value of each one of them.

```
let elements = document.getElementsByName('gender');
let isMale = elements[0].value === 'masc' || elements[1].value === 'masc';
```